# Class constructor expects either a float or a None. How do I account for float('nan') values?

Tags: python, casting, typing

I wrote a class in such a way that it expects either a `float` or a `None`. However, there's also a possibility of `float('nan')` values, as it turns out. I'm looking for a clean way to sort it out.

```
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PricingLimits:
    min_price   : Optional[float] = None
    min_percent : Optional[float] = None
    max_percent : Optional[float] = None
    min_delta   : Optional[float] = None
```

So far, I see two possibilities:

1. Forget about `None` and expect `float` exclusively. Work with `float('nan')` instead of `None`.
2. Somehow define a datatype that is a number-float: not `nan` (and not `inf`). I don't know how to do that but if did:

```
@dataclass
class PricingLimits:
    min_price   : Optional[NumberFloat] = None
    min_percent : Optional[NumberFloat] = None
    max_percent : Optional[NumberFloat] = None
    min_delta   : Optional[NumberFloat] = None
# And use a validator like Pydantic
```

Okay, I can also do this:

```
from pydantic import root_validator
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

@dataclass
class PricingLimits:
    min_price   : Optional[float] = None
    min_percent : Optional[float] = None
    max_percent : Optional[float] = None
    min_delta   : Optional[float] = None

    @root_validator
    def nan_to_none(cls, values):
        for k, v in values.items():
            if np.isnan(v):
                values[k] = None
        return values
```

That way all `nan` values would be automatically transformed into `None` upon object instantiation.

What's your take on this?

Comment: It depends on the logic of your code. What do NaNs mean to you? Are they equivalent to None as input? What shall happen? It's your decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do math using numpy or pandas it is better to keep `NaN` values as `np.nan` so I would do the opposite, I'd replace `None` with `np.nan`.

The main reason to use `np.nan` (over `None`) is that it can be stored with **numpy**'s `float64 dtype`, rather than the less efficient `object dtype`. `np.nan` allows for vectorized operations while `None`, by definition, disables all efficiency in **numpy**.

Another good reason is that `NaN` is used as a placeholder for missing data in **pandas**: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/missing_data.html)

```
import numpy as np

class PricingLimits:
    
    
    def __init__(self,
                    min_price: float = np.nan,
                    min_percent: float = np.nan,
                    max_percent: float = np.nan,
                    min_delta: float = np.nan):
        

        if not min_price:
            self.min_price = np.nan
        else:
            self.min_price = min_price
            
        if not min_percent:
            self.min_percent = np.nan
        else:
            self.min_percent = min_percent
            
        if not max_percent:
            self.max_percent = np.nan
        else:
            self.max_percent = max_percent
            
        if not min_delta:
            self.min_delta = np.nan
        else:
            self.min_delta = min_delta
```

If your goal is to have a value or `None` (this is the reason someone would use `Optional[x]`) and values are only set at instantiation, then converting `np.nan` to `None` at `init` is the right approach:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional

class PricingLimits:
    
    
    def __init__(self,
                    min_price: Optional[float] = None,
                    min_percent: Optional[float] = None,
                    max_percent: Optional[float] = None,
                    min_delta: Optional[float] = None):
        

        if not min_price or np.isnan(min_price):
            self.min_price = None
        else:
            self.min_price = min_price
            
        if not min_percent or np.isnan(min_percent):
            self.min_percent = None
        else:
            self.min_percent = min_percent
            
        if not max_percent or np.isnan(max_percent):
            self.max_percent = None
        else:
            self.max_percent = max_percent
            
        if not min_delta or np.isnan(min_delta):
            self.min_delta = None
        else:
            self.min_delta = min_delta
```

If you want to be free to change the value after instantiation you can use properties but **this will affect performance**:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional

class PricingLimits:
    
    @property
    def min_price(self):
        return self._min_price
    
    @min_price.setter
    def min_price(self, value):
        if not value or np.isnan(value):
            self._min_price = None
        else:
            self._min_price = value
            
    @property
    def min_percent(self):
        return self._min_percent
    
    @min_percent.setter
    def min_percent(self, value):
        if not value or np.isnan(value):
            self._min_percent = None
        else:
            self._min_percent = value
    
    @property
    def max_percent(self):
        return self._max_percent
    
    @max_percent.setter
    def max_percent(self, value):
        if not value or np.isnan(value):
            self._max_percent = None
        else:
            self._max_percent = value
    
    @property
    def min_delta(self):
        return self._min_delta
    
    @min_delta.setter
    def min_delta(self, value):
        if not value or np.isnan(value):
            self._min_delta = None
        else:
            self._min_delta = value
    
    def __init__(self,
                    min_price: Optional[float] = None,
                    min_percent: Optional[float] = None,
                    max_percent: Optional[float] = None,
                    min_delta: Optional[float] = None):
        
            self.min_price = min_price
            self.min_percent = min_percent
            self.max_percent = max_percent
            self.min_delta = min_delta
```

Comment: Replacing direct attribute access with a property will have an enormous performance impact if they're frequently referenced — so I don't think this is such a great approach since the checking is only needed during class construction.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I don't know if OP wants to set values only at instantiation, I edited my answer to include both scenario. It's a trade off between performance and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually really wanted to avoid all that clutter in the \_\_init\_\_ method but not sure if there is a good way to do it.

Comment: I don't know the purpose of your class but if you will use it with numpy and pandas I won't use Optional[float] at all but np.nan. See my first piece of code in the answer.